# Is it possible to call a variable from another function in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);


start_btn.buttonMode = true;
stop_btn.buttonMode = true;
start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStart, false, 0, true);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer, false, 0, true);
//stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter, false, 0, true);
function onStart(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var minutes:Number = Number(min_txt.text);
    var seconds:Number = Number(sec_txt.text);
    timer.start();
}

function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    minutes--;
    trace("Timer Triggered!!");
}
```

So how do i make it so that the "minutes--" works ..as the variables are in a seperate function..

(or give me another way)..

Thanks..

Comment: change the scope of `minutes` so that it is accessible to both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you declare variable in function, is a local variable. you not access variable other function, other scope. but if you declare in global variable. available anywhere.

Easy way, if you variable declared globally. It's available.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

start_btn.buttonMode = true;
stop_btn.buttonMode = true;
start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStart, false, 0, true);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer, false, 0, true);
//stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter, false, 0, true);
var minutes:Number;
function onStart(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
  minutes = Number(min_txt.text);
  var seconds:Number = Number(sec_txt.text);
  timer.start();
}

function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
  minutes--;
  trace("Timer Triggered!!");
}
```

Comment: are you updated your textfield at `onTimer` handler? below `minutes--;` line as follows: `min_txt.text = String(minutes);`

Comment: yes i did that too...and right now... i created a test variable    var test:Number;  and then gave it a value inside the "onStart" function.. test = Number("5");..and then i traced "test--" in the onTimer function...and its working like a charm...why is it not working with a text field??

Comment: I really don't understand. I wonder what exactly problem. umm.. would you give me a source code link?

Comment: Look at your original code, the variables was increased, good but problem that the variable is initialized as a textfield string value. your textfiled value is 0. so minutes 1->0 this statement infinite loop.

Comment: Here is solution: http://www.datafilehost.com/download-f5246402.html  I perfectly corrected your code. you should closely look at the code :)

Comment: thanks alot for the answer....the seconds work perfectly...but "minutes--" does not work...and when "minutes++" works in intervals of 2..also if you could tell me what you did in the "timeFormat" function...that'd be great..

Comment: I think, you want create a timer application. so i created a sample-code that code assume, always upcount. also `timeFormat function` is suitable digital clock format. bec int type show a 1,2,3,4... but, timer will shows 01,02,03,04... it's a great UX. it is common experience. look at the your digital watch.